# AngularJS Preventing Default Action on Button

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with multiple buttons. I want to have two different submit functions for each button. How can I achieve this?

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userCompany" placeholder="Company" ng-model="user.companyId" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userUsername" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.userId" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="userPassword" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default">Change Password</button>
  <span ng-show="errorData">{{errorData}}</span>
</form>
```

I'm trying to make Change Password do changePassword() instead.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `ng-submit` from your form element, and use ng-click on your two buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submitForm()">Submit</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="changePassword()">Change Password</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that it's not a submit button, by adding a `type="button"` to it.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="changePassword()" class="btn btn-default">Change Password</button>
```